# Unable to find assembly with BinaryFormatter.Deserialize

Tags: c#, deserialization

i hope you can help me.

i'm de-serializing a custom object and i'm getting this error.
the type is in a dll which is **loaded using a windows hook - thus, running under explorer.exe**

i understand why this error occurs, this because the DLL doesnt reside "explorer.exe" process.
there are 2 solutions for this:
1. install the assembly in GAC
2. use the "Binder" of the binary formatter.

i don't want to use any of those, as the DLL is actually loaded in explorer.exe (when i'm attaching, i see that the DLL is indeed loaded).

i'm serializing a custom object - **created in the same DLL that does the de-serializing**

this is my code:

```
     BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
     byte[] serializedObject;


        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
           binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, new MyCustomObject());
           serializedObject = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
      BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter2 = new BinaryFormatter();
      object deserializedObject;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream(serializedObject))
        {
           deserializedObject = binaryFormatte2r.Deserialize(memoryStream2); // Unable to find this assembly
        }
```

by the way. i've looked a bit in the binary formatter code, somehow it does tries to load the DLL.. but it's already loaded to the process..

error:

```
Unable to find assembly 'AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Key'.

stack trace:
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryConverter.TypeFromInfo(BinaryTypeEnum binaryTypeEnum, Object typeInformation, ObjectReader objectReader, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, InternalPrimitiveTypeE& primitiveTypeEnum, String& typeString, Type& type, Boolean& isVariant)
   at 
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadArray(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at 
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
```

-- edit--

i'm using namespace extensions (so the OS hooks to my dlls)

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing. Is that really one continuous code block? If so it does not make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: not really, just parts of code (we have a serialization manager).
the i_DataToSerialize should be "serializedObject" actually, i'll change that

Comment: Are you serializing and desirializing in the same AppDomain?

Comment: That assembly seems to be already loaded. This cannot be a loader problem *with that assembly* (do you agree?). Look elsewhere. Maybe you are misinterpreting the error message (post the full exception). Or, this is really about a different assembly than you thought.

Comment: Can you provide the Exact exception message and inner exceptions (if any)?

Comment: MrPaulch - yep, same appdomain - the thing is that it's a hook called from windows (thus from explorer.exe)

Alireza -
Unable to find assembly 'AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Key'.

no inner exception.

Comment: I suppose the name of the Assembly is not `AssemblyName`? If so the header of the binary file is somewhat generic, which could mean that something went wrong while serializing... I guess a generic AppDomain is created when hooking the dll? Im not sure though.

Comment: Parhaps it would help if you provide your binaryFormatter with a proper [SerializationBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Was the serialized blob generated from the exact same binary assembly that you try to deserialize it with? Maybe version or key have changed. Is the loaded assembly *exactly* named `AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=Key`?

Comment: MrPaulch - yep, the name of the assembly is not AssmeblyName (i've hidden the real name), and i did create a SerializationBinder (https://github.com/flcdrg/Gardiner.LoadedProjects/blob/master/Gardiner.LoadedProjects/AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder.cs) but i feel like it's not a good solution, as my DLL is loaded, so why should i load it again? (it seems like a weird workaround that i don't want in my project).

Comment: usr - the blob generated is EXACTLY the same as created from a standard console application (the console app succeeds with serialization as the DLL resides near the exe).
the loaded assembly is exactly as the one that is missing.

Comment: Have you attempted puting the dll into the `C:\Windows` folder? (it's a long shot)

Comment: MrPaulch - that would obviously work, but its not a valid solution as the dll may be called from any application with open file dialog ( as its a namespace extension). As i said, GAC or binding is a workaround, but before choosing it i want to understand why the binary formatter cant find a type in an already loaded to memory dll

Comment: From what I understand you serialize your object in some process `foo.exe` and you attempt to deserialize the object in `explorer.exe`. Now, when hooking a clr dll into a native process (or any process) the clr part is executed in some `DefaultAppDomain` - unless you configure it - so when the binaryFormatter is looking for the Assembly it won't know that it is already loaded into the memory unless you do [configure the AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxtzfyw3.aspx) to match the the one, in which the object was serialized, namely the one created by `foo.exe`

Comment: MrPaulch - it's partially true, i'm serializing the object in explorer.exe and desrializing in explorer.exe.
the thing is, that it's indeed a hook.

so that partially answers my question, you claim that although the DLL is loaded (i'm able to serialize in that app domain), the formatter can't find it?
can i prove it? can i see somehow that my DLL is loaded to appdomain X, and the formatter runs in the default domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too late, but my solution is shown below. The implementation of BindToType is overridden to solve your issue.

```
[Serializable]
public class YourClass : SerializationBinder 
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type tyType = null;
        string sShortAssemblyName = assemblyName.Split(',')[0];

        Assembly[] ayAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly ayAssembly in ayAssemblies)
        {
            if (sShortAssemblyName == ayAssembly.FullName.Split(',')[0])
            {
                tyType = ayAssembly.GetType(typeName);
                break;
            }
        }
        return tyType;
    }
    ...
```

[This link helped me](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5f0c371-b900-41d8-9a5b-1052739f2521/deserialize-unable-to-find-an-assembly-?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: we eventually did use the binder, but in a simpler manner:

    public override Type BindToType(string i_AssemblyName, string     i_TypeName)
          {
             Type typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("    {0}, {1}",
                 i_TypeName, i_AssemblyName));

             return typeToDeserialize;
          }

i'll mark yours as an answer, thanks!